# NSSlider custom subclass - how to maintain the link between the knob position and user interaction?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsslider

Trying to create a custom `NSSlider`. Overriding the `drawKnob()` method of the `NSSliderCell` changes the knob's appearance but doing this somehow disconnects the link between the knob's position and user interactions with the slider.

In the objective C example that is often referenced (https://github.com/lucasderraugh/LADSlider) it looks like when you override `drawKnob()` you then need to explicitly deal with the `startTracking` method, but I haven't found a solution that works for me - at the moment I am just setting the cell's startTracking 'at' property to the current value of the slider, but not sure what the right approach is.

Quite a few examples include an NSCoder argument in the cell's custom initialiser - I don't understand why, but maybe this has something to do with ensuring a connection between the display of the knob and the actual slider value?

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var seekSlider = NSSlider()
    var seekSliderCell = SeekSliderCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        super.viewDidLoad()
        seekSlider = NSSlider(target: self, action: #selector(self.seek(_:)))
        seekSlider.cell = seekSliderCell
        seekSlider.cell?.target = self
        seekSlider.cell?.action = #selector(self.seek(_:))
        seekSlider.isEnabled = true
        seekSlider.isContinuous = true
        view.addSubview(seekSlider)
    }
    
    @objc func seek(_ sender: NSObject) {
        
        let val = seekSlider.cell?.floatValue
        let point = NSPoint(x: Double(val!), y: 0.0)
        seekSlider.cell?.startTracking(at: point, in: self.seekSlider)
    }
}

class SeekSliderCell: NSSliderCell {
    
//  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
//      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
//  }
    
    override func drawKnob() {
        
        let frame = NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 6.0, width: 20.0, height: 10.0)
        let c = NSColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.0, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1.0)
        c.setFill()
        NSBezierPath.init(roundedRect: frame, xRadius: 3, yRadius: 3).fill()
    }

    override func startTracking(at startPoint: NSPoint, in controlView: NSView) -> Bool {

       return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Any clues in the documentation of `drawKnob`?

Comment: The documentation does mention the need to send a 'lockFocus()' message but if I call lockFocus() on the NSSlider I get a warning that it is deprecated and nothing has changed in the compiled app. There may be something around this I am missing I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of `drawKnob()` states:

> **Special Considerations**
> If you create a subclass of NSSliderCell, don’t override this method. Override drawKnob(_:) instead.

Instead of

```
func drawKnob()
```

override

```
func drawKnob(_ knobRect: NSRect)
```

Example:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var seekSlider = NSSlider()
    var seekSliderCell = SeekSliderCell()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        seekSlider = NSSlider(target: self, action: #selector(self.seek(_:)))
        seekSlider.cell = seekSliderCell
        seekSlider.cell?.target = self
        seekSlider.cell?.action = #selector(self.seek(_:))
        seekSlider.isEnabled = true
        seekSlider.isContinuous = true
        view.addSubview(seekSlider)
    }

    @objc func seek(_ sender: NSObject) {
        let val = seekSlider.cell?.floatValue
        print("\(String(describing: val))")
    }

}

class SeekSliderCell: NSSliderCell {

    override func drawKnob(_ knobRect: NSRect) {
        var frame = NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 6.0, width: 20.0, height: 10.0)
        frame.origin.x = knobRect.origin.x + (knobRect.size.width - frame.size.width) / 2
        frame.origin.y = knobRect.origin.y + (knobRect.size.height - frame.size.height) / 2
        let c = NSColor(red: 0.9, green: 0.0, blue: 0.6, alpha: 1.0)
        c.setFill()
        NSBezierPath.init(roundedRect: frame, xRadius: 3, yRadius: 3).fill()
    }

}
```

Comment: When I tried to 'hard code' an argument to the drawKnob method I received a "Method does not override any method from its superclass"... and when I tried to call drawKnob to pass in an actual NSRect argument I get 'Value of type 'NSCell?' has no member 'drawKnob'... I wonder if it is actually correct to link the control (slider) and its cell through 'seekSlider.cell = seekSliderCell' ...but couldn't see another way to do it

Comment: ...or I can literally just declare 'override func drawKnob(_ knobRect: NSRect) { ....' which does result in a knobRect property but doesn't fix the issue that the position of the knob is disconnected from user interactions with the slider

Comment: @chemFour I added an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your example. I had understood that '(_ knobRect: NSRect)' meant - pass in an NSRect but don't bother labelling this argument.  Can I ask, is there anything about the drawKnob(_:) documentation/ specification  that communicates to the programmer that the 'knobRect: NSRect' argument actually means that no argument needs to be passed in?

Comment: `func drawKnob(_ knobRect: NSRect)` has one argument and it's not optional.  [drawKnob()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsslidercell/1444606-drawknob/) and [drawKnob(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsslidercell/1444600-drawknob/) are two methods with almost the same name.

Comment: My question is about the fact that the NSRect property labelled 'knobRect' is never initialised (or is initialised internally automatically I guess). My understanding of ```func drawKnob(_ knobRect:NSRect)``` is that an initialised NSRect needs to be passed in. But... here no NSRect is ever initialised for knobRect. What about this ```drawKnob(_:)``` method makes it clear that ```knobRect: NSRect``` describes a property that is not actually initialised by the programmer?

Comment: It's in the syntax. `func functionName(_ paramA: Int, paramB: Int) {}` the part between `()` is the parameters. See [Functions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html). The slider intializes a `NSRect` and passes it to `drawKnob(_:)`.